# How do I create an action for a model with specific :id?

Tags: node.js, action, sails.js

So, I am using sails.js framework and I want to create an action "invite" for a user with id "5". Where should I place a function "invite"? I want to achieve a URL similar to this: "http://example.com/api/users/5/invite". Blueprints are ON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In routes.js add something like

`'post /api/users/:id/invite': 'UserController.invite'`

and then add your invite function in the UserController. The `id` param from the route will be available in `req.param('id')`

Comment: And how can I achieve same thing with blueprints?

Comment: If you want to use route params, you can't. You could use something like "http://example.com/api/user/invite?id=5" and just define your invite action and omit the route though.